# Using the same list with streams twice in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have to complete this trivial operation with streams: given a list, get the sum and the sum of the first 20 elements.

This is what I had in mind

```
IntStream stream = obj.stream().mapToInt(d->d.getInt());
stream.limit(20).sum() / stream.sum();
```

However I cant do this, since I am told I can't reuse a stream, so.. I tried the following:

```
List<Integer> counts = obj.stream()
    .mapToInt(d -> d.getInt())
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

counts.stream().limit(20).sum() / counts.stream().sum();
```

However I am told that I can't use sum on Stream, so I need to mapToInt again for left and right hand side of this trivial operation.

Is there a way to do this operation in a more elegant and concise way using streams?

Comment: With those constraints, it sound like the most elegant way is with a good 'ol `for` loop.

Comment: You could write a custom `Collator`...

Comment: Just get the stream twice from the list; with one with a limit. There's no need to overcomplicate things (custom collector or other) when it can be simple...

Comment: I think it is quite silly to repeat the mapToInt twice, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of collecting the numbers in a `List<Integer>`, you can turn them into an `int[]` with `toArray()`. This way, the code is a bit more compact, you don't have to box and unbox all the time, and you can turn that `int[]` directly into an `IntStream`.

```
int[] nums = obj.stream().mapToInt(d -> d.getInt()).toArray();
IntStream.of(nums).limit(20).sum() / IntStream.of(nums).sum();
```

Comment: This can also be generalized to numbers much larger than 20 (when avoiding double work becomes important) such that you store the "head" sum into a variable, then use `stream.skip(n).sum()` to sum up the rest. `skip` will be O(1) on an array. Just keep in mind that `skip` and `limit` do not parallelize. In that case, `Arrays.stream(array, offset, limit)` would be the best choice.

Answer (score 9):

There's a cool way to do this in a single parallel pass, but not using streams.

```
int[] nums = obj.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
Arrays.parallelPrefix(nums, Integer::sum);
int sumOfFirst20 = nums[19];
int sumOfAll = nums[nums.length-1];
```

The parallelPrefix method will compute the sequence of partial sums of the specified function (here, plus) on the array, in place.  So the first element is a0; the second is a0+a1, the third is a0+a1+a2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to overcomplicate things. Just get the stream twice from the list:

```
int totalSum = obj.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
int first20 = obj.stream().limit(20).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

Yes it will do two passes in the list (and the second time just for the 20 first elements so not a big deal), so I expect this is what they want you to do. It's simple, efficient and readable.

---

To do it in one pass you can use a collector. As an example, you can do it like this:

```
 Map<Boolean, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, obj.size())
                                      .boxed()
                                      .collect(partitioningBy(i -> i < 20, 
                                               mapping(i -> obj.get(i), 
                                                       summingInt(i -> i))));

int first20 = map.get(true);
int totalSum = map.get(true) + map.get(false);
```

Basically, you stream the indices first. Then for each indice; you'll split them in the map in two lists, one for the 20 first indexes, and the others in the other list; resulting in a `Map<Boolean, List<Integer>>`.

Then each index is mapped to its value in the original `List` (with the `mapping` collector).

Finally you transform each `List<Integer>` by summing their values into a single `Integer`. Then you just get the total sum.

Another workaround with a custom collector:

```
public static Collector<Integer, Integer[], Integer[]> limitSum(int limit, List<Integer> list) {
    return Collector.of(() -> new Integer[]{0, 0},
        (a, t) -> { a[0] += list.get(t); if(t < limit) a[1] += list.get(t); },
        (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; a[1] += b[1]; return a; },
        a -> a);
}
```

and an example of usage:

```
List<Integer> obj = Stream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1).limit(5).collect(toList()); //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Integer[] result = IntStream.range(0, obj.size())
                            .boxed()
                            .collect(limitSum(4, obj));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); //[10, 6]
```

---

As you can see it's not very readable and, as mentioned in comments, maybe a for-loop would be appropriate in this case (although you were asked to use Streams).